# Как вывести ссылки на предыдущий и следующий пост в категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как зациклить вывод постов , когда нажимаю на кнопки "Вперёд" или "Назад" , чтобы был переход в той же самой категории , что и предыдущий пост. А то сейчас, когда посты определенной категории кончаются , то он и другие посты других категории тоже показывает , а мне надо , чтобы , если посты определенной категории кончились, то нажав кнопку "вперёд" вывел первый пост этой категории , если пост первый и нажав кнопку "Назад" то перешёл на последний пост этой категории.

```
  if( get_adjacent_post(true, '', true) ) {
      previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="icon-button"></div> ');
  } else {
      $first = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"></a>';
      wp_reset_query();
   };

   if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) {
        next_post_link('%link', '<div class="icon-button"></div>');
   } else {
        $last = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"></a>';
        wp_reset_query();
   };
```

Answer (score -2):

> Как зациклить вывод постов , когда нажимаю на кнопки "Вперёд" или
>   "Назад" , чтобы был переход в той же самой категории , что и
>   предыдущий пост.

Добавить 3м параметром `true`
Например

`previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="icon-button"></div> ', true);`

см https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/

Comment: Да , но как сделать , когда все записи этой категории кончились , то нажав на "Вперед" показало первую запись ЭТОЙ категории?